# Can't get RegEx pattern to work correctly in MVC 5 View using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-views

Here is my pattern. I'm trying to allow numbers and a decimal with two places plus an optional comma with three digits.

```
var pattern = /^[0-9]+(,\d{3})*\.[0-9]{2}$/;
```

**Allow**

100,000.12

10,000.12

1,000.12

100.12

10.12

.12 (can't get this to allow... see below)

**Don't allow**

abcd

1,,000.12

1,00.12

1,000.0

1,000.

1,000

Here is the test. If I add a ? after [0-9] it works here, but it does not work in my MVC 5 View. The modal doesn't open, so MVC doesn't like it.

```
^[0-9]?+(,\d{3})*\.[0-9]{2}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/HwLS7q/1

**UPDATE 1**

Don't allow

000,000.12, 0.12 etc...

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[0-9]?+` is a pattern that matches 1 or 0 digits *possessively*, not allowing backtracking into the pattern. JS regex does not support [possessive quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117467/can-someone-explain-possessive-quantifiers-to-me-regular-expressions), hence the issue.

You need to use

```
^[0-9]*(?:,[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2}$
```

Or

```
^(?:[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]{3})*)?\.[0-9]{2}$
```

Here, the `[0-9]*` match zero or more digits and `(?:[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]{3})*)?` matches an optional sequence of 1+ digits followed with 0+ repetitions of `,` and 3 digit groups.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aTgmIu/3).

A *more precise pattern* would be to restrict the first digit chunk to 1, 2 or 3 digits and make the integer part optional:

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*)?\.[0-9]{2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aTgmIu/4).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `[0-9]{1,3}` - one to three digits
  - `(?:,[0-9]{3})*` - 0 or more repetitions of

    - `,` - comma
    - `[0-9]{3}` - three digits
- `\.` - dot
- `[0-9]{2}` - two digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: FYI, if you need to also match `100000.12`, add `\d+` alternative, `^(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*|\d+)?\.[0-9]{2}$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/aTgmIu/5)).

Comment: Thanks! I went with this one. ^(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*)?\.[0-9]{2}$ Any idea how to not allow something like 000,000.12 or 000.12 or 00.12 or 0.12?

Comment: @Dumber_Texan2 `^(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:,[0-9]{3})*)?\.[0-9]{2}$`, see https://regex101.com/r/aTgmIu/6

Comment: Thanks for the help! The answer plus your explanations were spot-on.